# Adding a column to existing csv file as an array (Python)

Tags: python, list, csv

Have a csv file called 'data.csv' in the following format:

```
test1,test2,test3
1,2,3
4,5,6
7,8,9
```

Given a list in the format ['test4', 4, 7, 10], how can I create a new csv file 'adjusted.csv' with all the data from data.csv and the added column like so:

```
test1,test2,test3, test4
1,2,3,4
4,5,6,7
7,8,9,10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

read lines in

```
with open('data.csv', 'r') as fi:
    lines = [[i.strip() for i in line.strip().split(',')] \
             for line in fi.readlines()]

col = ['test4', 4, 7, 10]
```

Concatenate each row with corresponding element of `col`.  Using enumerate to help keep track of which list index to use.

```
new_lines = [line + [str(col[i])] for i, line in enumerate(lines)]
```

Output to file

```
with open('adjusted.csv', 'w') as fo:
    for line in new_lines:
        fo.write(','.join(line) + '\n')
```

Answer (score 1):

I would just treat the csv like the raw text it is.  Load in each line, strip off the line break, append the new entry, then put the line break back.  **This only works if the entries in test4 are guaranteed to be in the same order as the rows in data.csv.**

If instead test4 needs to be added to rows based on meeting certain conditions, that would change things a lot.  In that case you would probably want to turn both into Pandas dataframes, then perform a proper merge on the required conditions.

```
test4 = ['test4', 4, 7, 10]

with open(data.csv, 'r') as ifile 
    with open(adjusted.csv, 'w') as ofile:
        for line, new in zip(ifile, test4):
            new_line = line.rstrip('\n') + ',' + str(new) + '\n'
            ofile.write(new_line)
```

You can also condense the first two lines into this:

```
with open(data.csv, 'r') as ifile, open(adjusted.csv, 'w') as ofile:
```

Do whichever reads more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're working with csv files use the `csv` `readers` and `writers` to improve readability:

```
import csv

new_data =  ['test4', 4, 7, 10]
with open(r'data.csv', 'r') as in_csv, open(r'adj_data.csv', 'w') as out_csv:
    reader = csv.reader(in_csv)
    writer = csv.writer(out_csv)
    for row, new_col in zip(reader, new_data):
        row.append(new_col)
        writer.writerow(row)
```